# Long processing time for JavaScript when generating pdf

Tags: pdf-reactor

I am using highcharts library to render charts to be converted to pdf using pdf reactor.

As long as simple charts are used, the time taken by pdf reactor is within few seconds.

When more complex charts are used, the J's processing time is significant up to 40 seconds.

Are there ways to reduce the overall Js processing time?

In my setup, I am using pdf reactor library jar v11.3 and loading the Js files using the pdf reactor configuration object. The HTML file will execute the scripts to render the charts on document load.

Comment: Have you tried generating the same PDFs using Adobe Acrobat or something similar?  That will give you a benchmark for comparison.  My #1 question is what is the file type of the charts?

Comment: @Raydot _Adobe Acrobat_ is not exactly a paragon of performance either, though. Amusingly...

Comment: ...and my 2nd question?

Comment: Where/how is this JS running? Server-side NodeJS? Client-side Electron? Browser-based? ServiceWorker? Is the JS rendering charts and images to those abominable Base64 `data:` URIs and passing them around as strings? Etc? etc?

Comment: @KJ I don't know what PDF libraries you're using, but a while ago I used a simple (low-level) PDF lib for .NET for generating PDFs via its PostScript-level commands and it had no problem generating PDFs containing hundreds of pages, with (raster) images and tabular data, in under a few seconds from a cold-start (high-throughput was from rendering pages concurrently on multiple threads). I'll bet the perf issues you and the OP are experiencing is because of some gross inefficiency somewhere - like, almost all "HTML-to-PDF" libs are just repackaged Qt+WebKit builds.

Comment: @Dai the application is spring boot application that uses thymeleaf to generate the html. The generated html is fed to pdf reactor.

Comment: I took a look through a disassembly of PDFReactor and I'll admit I'm impressed (somewhat): it looks like they actually did re-implement a CSS-based XML document page layout engine themselves - though the bulk of their `jar` libs are community libs from Mozilla, Apache, etc (XML, images, barcodes, PDF helper libs, etc) - but that does basically mean that PDFReactor can't be optimized for speed _because_ they went for flexibility because they implemented CSS (which is _hard!_), and having an intermediate HTML+CSS layout step is always going to significantly limit perf.

Comment: @Dai, thank you for looking into this and sharing your insights.